# Передать аргументы производного класса в базовый класс C#

Tags: c#, классы, конструктор

Есть 2 класса : ClassRoom и Pupil , Pupil к примеру это каждый отдельный ученик, конструктор ClassRoom должен принимать 3 аргумента типа Pupil

```
    class ClassRoom
{
    public ClassRoom()
    {

    }
}

class Pupil : ClassRoom
{
    public string Name;
    public string StudySkill;
    public string ReadingSkill;
    public string WritingSkill;
    public string RelaxingSkill;


    public Pupil(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Study(); // в этих методах просто возвращаю значение в поля StudySkill и тд
        Read();
        Write();
        Relax();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pupil student1 = new Pupil("aepot");
        Pupil student2 = new Pupil("thank");
        Pupil student3 = new Pupil("you");
    }
}
```

Не совсем понимаю как в конструктор ClassRoom передать аргументы типа Pupil.
возможно применение с : base() , но пробовал и никак не получалось

Comment: `class Pupil : ClassRoom` - Ученик не может быть Классной Комнатой.

Comment: @Igor спасибо , без наследование работает теперь всё, тему клоз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Pupil : ClassRoom` - Ученик не может быть Классной Комнатой.